Sci-Fi novel where explorers from Earth visited 3 planets
What is the title of a Sci-Fi novel where explorers from Earth visited 3 planets? I remember that these planets were occupied by certain groups of people and evolved over the years. The first planet was occupied by violent people. The second one was occupied by nudist. The last one was occupied by people who use work as payment for services.

Can you estimate the publishing date of the novel? What year did you read it? Can you describe the cover?

Just one nudist?

You are probably looking for the novel The Great Explosion, by Eric Frank Russell. Published in 1962, the three-part novel's final section is based on Russell's 1951 short story, "...And Then There Were None".

The following synopsis is quoted from Wikipedia:

The Blieder drive, a faster-than-light drive system, has permitted Earth to colonize the galaxy. Each planet has become home for a particular social group. Four hundred years after the diaspora (the "Great Explosion" of the title), a spaceship from Earth visits three of the planets, the first steps to unifying the galaxy under a new Empire. The ship contains two thousand Terrans including many pompous officials, an army of bureaucrats, a military force and the ship's crew, including some misfits. Things do not go entirely as hoped, as the incompetent military authoritarians of the ship encounter three very different societies.
The first planet was a penal colony; it is now many independent kleptocratic despotisms preying on each other. The second planet, Hygeia, is populated by health and fitness fanatic nudists. The third planet, Kassim, was colonized by a religious group, but when the ship arrives, the Terrans cannot find any human life, only empty villages overgrown by jungle. They decide not to land on the planet, because the captain fears that the colonists could have been killed by a disease and he doesn't want to endanger the crew. The final planet, K22g, has developed an unusual social system. The population call themselves Gands (after Gandhi) and practice a form of classless, philosophically anarchic libertarianism, based on passive resistance, and a moneyless gift economy based on barter and favor-exchange, using "obs", which is shorthand for "obligations". To perform a service for somebody "lays an ob" on them; they can then "kill the ob" by returning the favor. As the planet's population are demonstrably non-hostile, the officials have to approve shore leave, which brings the crew into contact with the anarchist natives. Many find reasons to stay on the planet, refusing to return to the ship. The officials have to get the ship back into space before they lose so many that the ship will never fly again.


I recognized "...And Then There Were None" but didn't have time to track it down.  Well done.

@Stanley Webb.  You beat me to it.

Not to be confused with Agatha Christie's multiple murder mystery And Then There Were None, originally published under a different name.
